# Collision between electron and atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atoms

In the [Franck-Hertz experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franck%E2%80%93Hertz_experiment), it is seen that an inelastic collision between 
an electron with the right energy and an atom, results in excitation of the atom. What are the dynamics of the energy transfer?

Answer (score 2):

Electrons and atoms are modeled using quantum mechanics. The simplest and first quantum model was the Bohr model which constrained by postulate that an electron is in a fixed radius around the atom,  as seen here for [the hydrogen](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html#c2) atom:

[image: hydr]

In this, the simplest atom, the electron will be stuck at the lowest energy level $n=1$. An incoming photon will transfer all its energy when hitting the electron and will either kick it out of the atom, if it has enough energy, or raise it to a higher energy level and be completely absorbed in the process if it has, within a width, the appropriate energy (otherwise it will scatter off elastically). The electron in the excited state will decay spontaneously to the lower level emitting a photon  with a time constant given by the width of the level.

The theory of [quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics) using [Schrodinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) gives the same solutions, but also the probabilities of these scatters to happen.